How to know when a Flutter package was released/published?
I don't want to know when the last release was.
I want to know when the first release was.
I have tried searching in search engines for the package like:

When the flutter_package_name was released?

But no luck in that.

To know when a Flutter package was released:
1. Go to the package page in pub.dev

2. Press on Versions


3. Scroll down to the bottom, there you will find the date of the first release


Open pub.dev and search which package do you want to know.
Under the package name and platforms there is a row of readme, example, versions etc.
You have to open versions. Scroll bown and last one is the the first relase of that package. Date also mentioned there.
